# Need help on applying heat map analysis on pandas DataFrame in Jupiter notebook

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, heatmap, data-analysis

Need help on applying heat map analysis on pandas DataFrame in Jupiter notebook based on some condition like if rows count less than 100 should display that cell as red else green. Please advise which python packages will help and how to apply condition to display as required.

I have data like this...
[image]

Comment: Have a look at pandas styler functions: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Styler-Functions

Comment: Please don't add data or code as images. Instead use plain text or better yet, provide a piece of code that constructs the dataframe. This will make it much more likely that someone is quickly able to help you.